# Any good desktop client for wordpress with support for google syntax highliter?

Tags: visual-editor, plugin-syntaxhighlighter

I'm using [Google Syntax Highlighter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/google-syntax-highlighter/) for WordPress and I have to go to the html view where I have to manually type the  tags for pasting code and formatting gets messed up when I switch back to the WYSIWYG view.

Is there a desktop client like windows live writer that has support for Google Syntax Highlighter and allows us to paste code and format the post in the same view?

Answer (score 1):

While it isn't exactly what you're looking for, I would recommend just spending all your time in the HTML editor. That's what I do. I have never found a WYSIWYG editor that produces clean code - especially when switching back and forth from HTML to WYSIWYG.